# C# class organisation / structure - generalising a class performing a looping linear interpolation

Tags: c#, oop, parameters, xna

I'm working on a C# XNA game, and have the following code which updates a Sprite's alpha level based on the result of a linear interpolation:

```
class AlphaProcess : GameProcess {

    Sprite sprite;
    public Sprite Sprite {
        get { return sprite; }
        set { sprite = value; }
    }

    float start;
    public float Start {
        get { return start; }
        set { start = value;}
    }

 ...<snip>...

    public override void Update(float elapsed) {
        if (FirstUpdate) {
            Start = sprite.Alpha;
            FirstUpdate = false;
        }

        Time += elapsed;
        if (Time >= Duration)
            Finished = true;

        sprite.Alpha = MathHelper.Lerp(start,end,Time/Duration);
    }
}
```

'Start' (float), 'FirstUpdate' (bool), 'Time' (float), 'Duration' (float) are all fields of class AlphaProcess. 'Sprite' is a class containing details such as scale, position, direction, rotation etc.

The 'Update' method is called 60 times a second, calculating a new alpha value for the sprite over a specified time period. When it's done the GameProcess is removed from a queue.

This code works fine, however it's very specific. The Sprite class I have contains lots of properties that it would be handy to lerp over a fixed period of time (rotation, position (for easing in and out)). Many of these variables are also floats. It seems silly to create multiple 'GameProcess'-extending classes that do pretty much the same thing, just on a different variable. However, I can't think of how to best refactor this so that I can just have a pointer to a float value being modified, rather than the specific sprite and it's alpha / rotation / scale / whatever value.

I've been through the C# reference / value / parameter passing questions on SO and know in C# you can't store a reference as a field. The 'GameProcessQueue' which calls Update knows nothing of the internals of the 'GameProcess' being updated. **Is there a smarter way of doing this so I can generalise / abstract the class to update a field of another class (like here, with the 'Alpha' field of 'Sprite')?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that your AlphaProcess class has low cohesion.  It has three main roles, Tweening, Lerping and getting/setting a Sprite Alpha Value.  To improve your design, you need to split these into separate decoupled classes.

**Goal:** Turn your AlphaProcess into a TweenProcess.

Instead of passing it a sprite, pass it an interface through which it can get and set the float it wishes to operate on. And instead of calling Lerp directly, pass it an interface or delegate to a Tween function.  *(I've used an interface instead of a delegate because I've found delegates often create garbage which can cause your game to stutter.)*

**The tweening class is:**

```
interface IFloatPropertySource
{
    float FloatProperty { get; set; }
}

interface ITweenFunction
{
    float Tween(float start, float end, float t);
}

class TweenProcess : GameProcess 
{
    float start;
    IFloatPropertySource floatSource;
    ITweenFunction tweenFunction;

    public TweenProcess(IFloatPropertySource floatSource, ITweenFunction tweenFunction)
    {
        this.floatSource = floatSource;
        this.tweenFunction = tweenFunction;
    }

    public override void Update(float elapsed) {
        if (FirstUpdate) {
            start = floatSource.FloatProperty;
            FirstUpdate = false;
        }

        Time += elapsed;
        if (Time >= Duration)
            Finished = true;

        floatSource.FloatProperty = tweenFunction.Tween(start, end, Time / Duration);
    }
}
```

**The class to get/set the alpha is:**

```
class SpriteAlphaSource : IFloatPropertySource
{
    Sprite sprite;

    public SpriteAlphaSource(Sprite sprite)
    {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }

    public float FloatProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return sprite.Alpha;
        }
        set
        {
            sprite.Alpha = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I know you're sort of trying to avoid having this class. But all the ways around it, like via reflection are really expensive.  In a project that has more renderables than just sprites, you may want to decouple it from sprite and make it operate on a base interface like IRenderable instead.

**The lerping mechanism is:**

```
class Lerp : ITweenFunction
{
    public float Tween(float start, float end, float t)
    {
        return MathHelper.Lerp(start, end, t);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right - "I know you're sort of trying to avoid having this class" - but this is still a much better way of structuring what I have. Incidentally I already have a class for 'Animations' (basically implementing what you've called 'ITweenFunction', just not for AlphaProcess (and SO brevity). Going to try this out now, thanks!

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, why 'm_' prefix?

Comment: No worries.  Great question.  The m_ (member variable) prefix is a legacy from C++ and is not best practice here.  I've removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you pass a callback function into the Update class-- in C# terms, you use a delegate function. Add a property to your class that looks like

```
public delegate SetThis(float value) { get; set; }
```

To set that, in client code you do something like

```
myAlphaProcess.SetThis = ( x => sprite.Alpha = x; )
```

And in the Update() function, you have

```
SetThis(MathHelper.Lerp(start,end,Time/Duration));
```

The syntax in this answer is *approximate*, because I don't have a compiler at this computer, but this is how you do it. Good google searches would be "lambda C#" or "delegate C#".

Comment: It should be noted that a *ton* of delegates like this are predefined for you as: `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2>`... and `Func<T>`, `Func<T, R>`, `Func<T1, T2, R>` `Actions` are the delegates returning void, and `Func`s return their last Type parameter.

Comment: Actually, sorry, having a bit of trouble with this.. could you elaborate on what goes where?

Answer (score 1):

This can be a generic approach to that matter... maybe you should do a TweenManager and add the Tweenables to a collection for update only active Tweenables...

This should be right, but I have not checked it ... maybe generics give any problem... with calcs, but should be avoided with the generic delegate... :)

```
Tweenable<float> Alpha = new Tweenable(defaultvalue);

public class Tweenable<T>
{
     public T  Value {
           get { return Function(elapsed, source, target-source, duration);} 
           private set { source = value; elapsed = 0;}
     }

     public TweeningFunction<T> Function;

     float elapsed, duration;
     T source, target;

     public void Update(float Elapsed)
     {
          if (elapsed<duration) 
          {
              elapsed+= Elapsed;
              if (elapsed > duration) elapsed = duration;
          }
     }

     public void Start(T Source, T Target, float Duration)
     {
         ...
     }
}

 public delegate T TweeningFunction( float timeElapsed, 
                                           T start, 
                                           T change, 
                                           float duration );


public static partial class Tweening {    
        public static class Quartic {
            public static float EaseIn( float t, float b, float c, float d ) {
                return c * (t /= d) * t * t * t + b;
            }
            public static float EaseOut( float t, float b, float c, float d ) {
                return -c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t - 1) + b;
            }
            public static float EaseInOut( float t, float b, float c, float d ) {
                if ( (t /= d / 2) < 1 ) {
                    return c / 2 * t * t * t * t + b;
                }
                return -c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t - 2) + b;
            }
        }
    }
```